# How to access the content div on a Wordpress post/page?

Tags: wordpress

I was looking to add some jquery via a plugin and needed to reference the div within which all the content is displayed.

I'm essentially trying to insert a new div within the content based on some variables for which I need some attributes like the width of the content area, the p tags in the content area, etc.

Is there a universal Wordpress method which I can access to reference the content hook in javascript and/or CSS?

Comment: This sounds like your problem lies outside of WordPress core... the containing DIVs are all setup inside your theme files. Even if you hooked into the_content filter, it would not affect any DIVs unless the DIV is a part of the content (not the theme).

Comment: I'm actually looking for the parent div of the content area to give me access to all internal elements of the DOM.

Comment: If you're using jQuery or JavaScript, you'll have access to the entire DOM. You don't need to "get access". You should take a look at Firebug plug-in for Firefox to help you find the div's ID or class, from there you can manipulate within jQuery/JS.